# Math Processing Error in Chrome 19.0.1084.56

Tags: support, mathjax

Yesterday I updated Chrome to 19.0.1084.56 (the newest version) and am experiencing Math Processing Errors abound. What I mean by this is that none of the MathJax or LaTeX renders properly - see below.

[image]

This was just a recent question at the top on the front page. Is anyone else experiencing this? In addition, the script for rendering Mathjax no longer works in Chat for me when I am using Chrome 19.0.1084.56. Any suggestions besides trying to install an older version of Chrome?

Comment: Just for reference, the picture in the post is the title from [this math.SE post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/158304/264) (this is so people can compare what they see on the same page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting my browser cache for the last four weeks and then pressing shift + F5 (refresh) worked for me - LaTeX is rendering fine for now. The script for rendering LaTeX in the Chat also works fine as well now.

To delete your browser cache in Chrome, see [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95582).